Evaluating a sum of Bessel functions over linear Diophantine equation solutions
I am working on a signal processing project, and have encountered this question.
Using $J$ as Bessel functions of the first kind, and with $x$, $y$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ as real numbers, I need to sum the expression:
$$J_{j}(x) \ e^{ij\theta}\ J_{k}(y) \ e^{ik\phi}$$
over all ordered pairs of integers $(j,k)$ such that $ja+kb=c$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all integers, given $c$ is divisible by $\text{gcd}(a,b)$.
I recognise that this is a linear Diophantine equation, whose solution space is:
$$\begin{bmatrix} j \\ k \end{bmatrix} = \frac{c}{\text{gcd}(a,b)} \begin{bmatrix} j_{0} \\ k_{0} \end{bmatrix}+\frac{n}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}\begin{bmatrix} b \\ -a \end{bmatrix} \quad\ \text{for} \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
where $(j_{0},k_{0})$ is one particular solution to $j_{0}a+k_{0}b=\text{gcd}(a,b)$.
Using $g$ as $\text{gcd}(a,b)$, I believe the sum then becomes:
$$e^{i\frac{c}{g}(j_0+k_0)}\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}J_{cj_{0}/g+bn/g}(x) \ J_{ck_{0}/g-an/g}(y) \ e^{i\frac{n}{g}(b\theta-a\phi)}.$$
Any advice, solutions, or useful formulae to evaluate this are appreciated. Approximate solutions also welcome.
